# AWS Cloudformation [/Resources/PrivateGateway/Properties] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to run a Cloudformation template to create a private API Gateway, I am getting a null value error, not able to figure out why,
**Following is the template I'm trying to work with -**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Api Template Stack

Parameters:
    VpcId:
        Type: String
        Default: "vpc-xxxxxx"

Resources:
    PrivateGateway:
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
        Properties:
        Name: 'private-gw'
        EndpointConfiguration:
            Types:
            - PRIVATE
        Policy: !Sub |
          {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:*/*/*/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": !Ref VpcId
                    }
                }
                },
                {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:*/*/*/*"
                }
            ]
          }
```

**Error -**

```
[/Resources/PrivateGateway/Properties] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, this appears to be a yaml parsing error, rather than a CloudFormation error.

Because this is a yaml template, it is subject to the [yaml specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Basic).

> Each node must be indented further than its parent node. All sibling nodes must use the exact same indentation level. However the content of each sibling node may be further indented independently.

In your example, the nodes under `Properties` are not indented further, so they are not considered children of that node, but siblings.  This is very likely why you are getting a 'null' values message, as the `Properties` node is considered 'empty' or 'null'.

Try adding two spaces at the beginning of every line under the 'Properties:' line.  This will make the nodes such as `Name`, `EndpointConfiguration`, and `Policy` as child nodes to the `Properties` node.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, indentation was indeed one of the issues in the template

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve it using the Curly braces for substituting the VpcId in the Policy -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Api Template Stack

Parameters:
    VpcId:
        Type: String
        Default: "vpc-xxxxxx"

Resources:
    PrivateGateway:
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
        Properties:
            Name: 'private-gw'
            EndpointConfiguration:
                Types:
                - PRIVATE
            Policy: !Sub |
            {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Deny",
                        "Principal": "*",
                        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:*/*/*/*",
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringNotEquals": {
                                "aws:sourceVpc": "${VpcId}"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": "*",
                        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:*/*/*/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
```